# Use the Mean Value Theorem to prove something about tangents to a graph

Tags: calculus

Use the Mean Value Theorem to prove that there is a point $c$ in the interval $[4,6]$ such that the line tangent to the graph of $f(x)=x^2-10x+25$ at $c$ is horizontal.
Can we use the same theorem to say the same about the function
$g(x)=|x-5|$?
Yes or No?

Answer (score 3):

$f(4)=f(6)$. Using the mean value theorem, we know that there exists $c$ in $(4,6)$ such that $$f'(c)=\frac{f(6)-f(4)}{6-4}=0$$ This does not work for the function $g$, because $g$ is not differentiable at every point in the interval [4,6].

Comment: Consider one small change: "... because $g$ is not differentiable *at every point* on that interval."

Comment: OK I will change it